# How to Create Relationship Between Contact and Account SugarCRM javascript

Tags: javascript, contacts, sugarcrm, accounts

Hi can somebody help me? I am new in programing with Javascript and I need to set a Contact to Account Relationship.

```
function SetRelationContact_Account(){
    $.get(CurrentServerAddress + '/service/v2/rest.php', {
        method: "set_relationship",
        input_type: "JSON",
        response_type: "JSON",
        rest_data: '{"session":"' + SugarSessionId +
        '","module_name":"Contacts","module_id":"' + CurrentContactId +
        '","link_field_name":"accounts","related_ids":["session":"' + SugarSessionId +
        '"]}'
    }, function(data) {
        if (data !== undefined) {
            var addAccountResult = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

        }

    });
}
```

I tried to create new Contact and I want to set a Relationship with an existing Account.
At jmertic's suggestion, I tried the following, but it still didn't work:

```
function SetRelationContact_Account(){
    $.get(CurrentServerAddress + '/service/v2/rest.php', {
        method: "set_relationship",
        input_type: "JSON",
        response_type: "JSON",
        rest_data: '{"session":"' + SugarSessionId + '","module_name":"Contacts","module_id":"' + CurrentContactId + '","link_field_name":"accounts","related_ids":["name":"account_id","value":"' + CurrentAccountId + '"]}'
   }, function(data) {
       if (data !== undefined) {
           var addAccountResult = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

       }

   });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

"related_ids" should be the Account Id of the record you are relating to, and should be in the form of a javascript array.

Comment: @MichelangeloMik: The best place to post new code that you've tried is as an update to your original question. I've done that for you in this case. The "edit" link underneath the question tag area allows you to edit your question. Welcome to stackoverflow!